# Spy return value is not work correctly in Service test using jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, testbed

I'm not able to correctly mock my return value of a function inside my injected service in my Angular test.

I'm using:

jasmine v2.8.0 and 
jasmine-core v2.8.0

I simplified the code to make it easier to understand. Here it is...

This is my Service what I want to test:

```
export class NetworkService {

  testNumber = 0;

  constructor(private networkReducerService: NetworkReducerService) {
    this.testNumber = networkReducerService.getNumber();
  }
}
```

This is my `spec.ts`

```
describe('NetworkService', () => {

  let service: NetworkService;
  let networkReducerServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<NetworkReducerService>;

  beforeEach(() => {

    const nRServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('NetworkReducerService', ['getNumber']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [NetworkService,
        {provide: NetworkReducerService, useValue: nRServiceSpy}
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(NetworkService);
    networkReducerServiceSpy = TestBed.get(NetworkReducerService);
  });

  it('should have the following fields', () => {

    networkReducerServiceSpy.getNumber.and.returnValue(1);

    expect(networkReducerServiceSpy.getNumber).toHaveBeenCalled();

    expect(service.testNumber).toBe(1);
  });

});
```

I want to mock this getNumber method inside my `NetworkReducerService`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NetworkReducerService {
  getNumber() {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

Error: Expected undefined to be 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into an "a before b" issue.  You make the call to set `testNumber` in the constructor of your `NetworkService` class.  Therefore it is called when you first create the class - long before you change the value of your spy.  Either set the value before you instantiate the service, or refactor your `NetworkService` to set the value inside a method that can be tested by invoking after creation, rather than the constructor.